# C-Move Query - How to move only specific series within study using only Study Instance UID?

Tags: dicom

I would like to perform a C-move to retrieve only specific images within a study, in stead of having to move the entire study which contains some large size scans I won't use.

I have set up a working Q/R Node, and I have a list of Study UIDs. I could potentially match the specific images based on 'series description' (0008,103e).

My question: Is this possible? and how should I best approach this problem?

I plan to access the PACS with either pynetdicom or dcmtk. How can I check the DICOM conformance statement for my PACS? echoing results are posted below:

Comment: This depends on your PACS. If it supports querying by Series Description, you can use it, but this is not mandatory. Check the DICOM conformance statement for your PACS.

Comment: Also, you should say what you using for PACS access.

Comment: May be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322106/5779732

Comment: The DICOM conformance statement is provided by the PACS vendor, most can be found online.

Answer (score 2):

1. The output of the verification (C-ECHO) that you posted does not tell anything about the Query/Retrieve capabilities of your PACS

*(The following is over-simplified and does not count if both applications support relational queries. But this is rarely found in the field. So I am describing baseline behavior here which is found in every DICOM conformance Query/Retrieve SCP)*

2. C-MOVE is desinged based on Unique identifiers. You must include all Unique Identifiers of the levels above the level you are putting your request (in your case: SERIES) and a Unique Identifier identifying the subject you want to retrieve. Having said that you only have the Study Instance UID (i.e. no patient ID) limits you to the Study-Root Query/Retrieve Information model. You request is supposed to include the Study Instance UID (0020,000d) and the Series Instance UID (0020,000e). Apart from MOVE command specific attributes (e.g. Query Retrieve Level (0008,0052)) no other matching keys are allowed for your C-MOVE command.

*In particular: You are not allowed to specify the Series Description as a matching criterion for the C-MOVE Request!*

3. That is, you are obliged to request the MOVE of Series Instance UIDs of interest.
4. The remaining task is to (C-)Find the appropriate Series Instance UIDs you want to move. You have to use the C-FIND command to do so.
5. The C-FIND command will be sent on SERIES level, include the Stuy Instance UID and further matching criteria *on the SERIES level* restricting the matches, e.g.

- Series Description
- Modality
- Number Of Series Related Instances
- ...

...and the Series Instance UID as a return key (sent with zero-length). As @MrBeanBremen wrote, there are only few attributes on which you can rely that the PACS can match them. For Study Root, they are described in PS3.4, C.6.2.1. Everything beyond that is an optional feature of the PACS and subject to its Conformance Statement

6. This will give you a list of Series Instance UIDs. Each of these needs to be sent with its own C-MOVE command as described in 2.

> Reference: PS3.4, Section C (Query/Retrieve Service Class)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understand it correctly; The first thing I should do is to use C-FIND with my known Study Instance UID to retreive Series instance UID. Then I can move down a level, query on Series level, and perhaps then I can use the Study UID, the Series UID, and the SOP Class UI to get the secondary screen captures I am looking for. (if accepted by the conformance statement of Sectra)